# C# IntelliSense for enum type

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, enums, intellisense

I recently moved from VB to C# and I miss the way VB handle IntelliSense behavior for enum types.

In VB, when you assign or compare am enum value, the IntelliSense will open the list of enum values directly.

In C#, the IntelliSense will only select the enum type in the list, forcing me to type a "." to get the list of enum values.

Is there a way to reproduce VB enum behavior in C# (without third party plugin)?

Comment: Is pressing `.` really that much work?

Comment: Yes, you have the extra `.` keystroke but think how many you saved by not typing `End Function` all of the time!

Comment: @ p.s.w.g.  It's not that bad... but if I can fix it, I will.

Comment: @James I don't want to start a VB / C# debate but I worked in VB for several years and I never typed End Function manually as VS is writing it for you once you complete function declaration.  However, now I have to type a ; at the end of every line of code I write.

Comment: On the flip side, try doing a `switch` (equivalent of select in VB) with an enum: it automatically creates a case for every enum value. Personally I will take that over having to enter a `.` when picking a value.

Comment: @Obsidian Phoenix Yes, I like this feature too.  In fact, I think both features should be available (and optional) in both language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that *specific* feature is part of Microsoft's [Visual Basic-Specific IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxy240ac.aspx)

> ### Automatic Completion
>
> - Completion on various keywords
>
>   > For example, if you type goto and a space, IntelliSense will display a list of the defined labels in a drop-down menu. Other supported keywords include Exit, Implements, Option, and Declare.
> - **Completion on Enum and Boolean**
>
>   > When a statement will refer to a member of an enumeration, IntelliSense will display a list of the members of the Enum. When a statement will refer to a Boolean, IntelliSense will display a true-false drop-down menu.

You should get it to pop up through regular intellisense by hitting `.` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, though.